# No option to boot Ubuntu after Windows 10 update in dual boot

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I had Ubuntu 16 and Windows 10 installed and coexisting peacefully.

On boot, the past and wise me had configured the computer so that it would give me a choice on whether I would like to boot Ubuntu or Windows, on a timer that would start Ubuntu by default if 30 seconds without input passed.

But the last Windows 10 update has disabled the possibility of booting Ubuntu altogether.

What I have tried:

- I entered the power options on Windows 10 and disabled fast boot
- I have shutdown the computer while pressing shift, then pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> on boot to access the BIOS menu. There I have checked that indeed my first boot option is Ubuntu, and I have also tried disabling a fast boot option there was there in the BIOS menu.

I do not know what else to try.

How can I return the boot configuration to its behaviour pre update?

---

UPDATE:

- I have tried running `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` from the console with admin rights. When I load, now I see a scary screen saying

  > Secure Boot Violation. Invalid signature detected. Check secure Boot Policy in setup
- I have also tried booting from a live USB. Got into BIOS menu using <kbd>F2</kbd> on boot, then when I launch the boot override... I get the same scary message as above.

Comment: grubx64.efi is not signed, use /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi or turn secure boot off.

Comment: @ravery I have tried running `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`. I get the same `Secure Boot Violation` message. How do I disable secure boot?

Comment: boot into the firmware settings by holding one of the function keys.... often F2 or F10 but could be any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably boot to an Ubuntu live disk/USB and run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to restore your GRUB bootloader, thus, hopefully fixing your Windows or Ubuntu choice on boot.

Comment: Tried, it prompted a "secure boot violation" see update in the Question :(

Comment: Have you [disabled secure boot](https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1811) in your BIOS?

Comment: It worked! Now running Boot Repair

Comment: Fantastic! You should be good to go after running that. Note, you can easily edit your GRUB configuration from within Ubuntu using [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer). I use it all the time for my Windows + 3 distro setup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your partitions? The Windows 10 Creators update is known to delete linux partitions.

In most cases, restoring the partition is sufficient to restore boot unless you have made other changes.

`testdisk` is a good program for recovering partitions and is available from the repository.

Comment: How do I check the partitions? How can I run testdisk from Windows?

Comment: boot from a LiveCD. Windows can not read linux partitions.