# Can't boot ubuntu anymore after Windows 10 update

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I used to be able to select either the Windows Boot Manager or Ubuntu when booting my ASUS laptop.

Since Windows 10 has updated, it now automatically chooses the windows boot manager. Ubuntu is the first in the boot priority list, and even if I press escape during startup to manually choose a boot device, and then choose ubuntu, it still loads up the windows boot manager.

I have disabled secure boot, fast boot, and hibernation. This all used to work until the latest Windows 10 update. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No option to boot Ubuntu after Windows 10 update in dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984703/no-option-to-boot-ubuntu-after-windows-10-update-in-dual-boot) and [Windows 10 update broke my MBR / GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874181/windows-10-update-broke-my-mbr-grub)

Answer (score 0):

During the Windows 10 update process, Windows 10 decided to overwrite your MBR bootloader. Which in the case before the update, was GRUB.

But after the update, Windows 10 replaced GRUB with BOOTMGR, Windows 10's bootloader.

### 1. Getting a `boot-repair` disk

boot-repair is a program that can:

- send computer info to Pastebin
- ***install GRUB on the bootloader***
- configure grub
- and more!

If you run a 64-bit system, go [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso/download)

If you run a 32-bit system, go [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/boot-repair-disk-32bit.iso/download)

### 2. ***Etching*** the image to a disk

Ironically, we will be using the popular image writer, Etcher.

To download Etcher, go [here](http://etcher.io)

Basically, just select your downloaded `boot-repair-disk` .iso
 file and select a USB device.

***WARNING: THIS CAN ERASE ALL DATA FROM YOUR USB. USE THIS PROGRAM WITH CAUTION.***

### 3. Booting up.

To boot up to `boot-repair`, attach your USB disk, power on your computer, then start pressing the 'boot from...' key.

Select your disk.

You should start to boot up.

When you see a window that is titled, boot-repair or something similar...

Select Automated fix or the 1st option.

Only select "more options" if you are an experienced Linux user or have a friend to help!

It should start reinstalling and configuring GRUB (should be the latest one depending on your disk version).

When it is done, reboot if it asks you to. If it does not, open the power menu, and select reboot.

This time, select your boot disk (hard drive, SSD, etc.)\

You should see a menu. (GRUB!)

Select Windows or Ubuntu.

You should boot to said OS!

Follow this guide whenever you update Windows 10.

I hope this guide helped!