# Ubuntu won't boot after a Windows update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb

When I installed Ubuntu a year ago, I created a partition (alas) on which I kept Windows, just in case. I've been booting in Windows extremely rarely because I work from Ubuntu only. Two days ago (alas again) I booted in Windows and naturally a ton of updates were waiting for me. So I did the updates choosing "Update and shut down". After that shutdown, however, both Windows and Ubuntu are failing to boot. Windows freezes in "Preparing Automatic Repair" and Ubuntu mostly just gives a black screen (sometimes it says "TPM interrupt not working, polling instead) although I did reach the purple screen twice, managed to enter my password but then it froze.

In UEFI, the computer (HP Zbook mobile workstation, i7) passes the system fast test, on the extensive test it passes the short DST check but freezes on the optimized DST check.

A boot through advanced Ubuntu options/recovery mode also doesn't work (it runs for a while giving error messages like kernel panic, etc. and then freezes).

I've created a live USB stick (which works, I've just used it to install Ubuntu on another computer) but also that won't boot, not even in the safe graphics mode, it starts booting and then freezes. (I've disabled Fast Boot in UEFI).

Is there any way this can be solved? I haven't done a back-up in a week and if nothing else I'd like to recover some of the data from that disk.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Boot Windows directly in UEFI. If it works then make sure it installs all pending updates, disable Fast Startup, a must when dual-booting and SHUTDOWN. Then change the boot order back to Ubuntu and try booting Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No option to boot Ubuntu after Windows 10 update in dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984703/no-option-to-boot-ubuntu-after-windows-10-update-in-dual-boot)

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. Windows won't boot from UEFI

Comment: It wouldn´t boot from a Windows USB, also it didn´t boot from a Fedora USB. It's always the same, I can reach Grub, I can play with BIOS, it starts booting, then it freezes. This morning for the first time I managed to log into Ubuntu after I reset all the BIOS settings, it seemed like it was working I launched Thunderbird then the screen started flashing and the computer froze again.

Comment: I couldn't log in again. I took the SSD out, managed to recover all the data, restored it on another computer and formatted the SSD, erasing the Windows partition. I put the formatted SSD back into the computer, inserted a live Ubuntu USB and still it won't boot. It starts booting, then it freezes. When I tried to boot in the safe graphics mode I got "Kernel panic - not syncing - fatal exception". When I tried again I got "kernel stack is corrupted in: vt_console_print+0x48a/0x4e0". Any ideas?